# Spring Projections not returning the State Details

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-projections

I have a Country and State table for which I have integrated with Spring Data JPA. I have created a function `public Page<CountryDetails> getAllCountryDetails` in my CountryServiceImpl for getting all the Country and the corresponding State details. The service is working fine and is giving me the below output:

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "id": 123,
      "countryName": "USA",
      "countryCode": "USA",
      "countryDetails": "XXXXXXXX",
      "countryZone": "XXXXXXX",
      "states": [
        {
          "id": 23,
          "stateName": "Washington DC",
          "countryCode": "USA",
          "stateCode": "WAS",
          "stateDetails": "XXXXX",
          "stateZone": "YYYYYY"
        },
        {
          "id": 24,
          "stateName": "Some Other States",
          "countryCode": "USA",
          "stateCode": "SOS",
          "stateDetails": "XXXXX",
          "stateZone": "YYYYYY"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "last": false,
  "totalPages": 28,
  "totalElements": 326,
  "size": 12,
  "number": 0,
  "sort": null,
  "numberOfElements": 12,
  "first": true
}
```

My Complete code is as given below:

**CountryRepository.java**

```
@Repository
public interface CountryRepository extends JpaRepository<CountryDetails, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT country FROM Country country GROUP BY country.countryId ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}", 
    countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Country country GROUP BY country.countryId ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}")
    public Page<CountryDetails> findAll(Pageable pageRequest);
}
```

**CountryServiceImpl.java**

```
@Service
public class CountryServiceImpl implements CountryService {

    @Autowired
    private CountryRepository countryRepository;

    @Override
    public Page<CountryDetails> getAllCountryDetails(final int page, final int size) {
        return countryRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(page, size));
    }
}
```

**CountryDetails.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "country", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "id"))
public class CountryDetails {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;
    private String countryName;
    private String countryCode;
    private String countryDetails;
    private String countryZone;

    @JsonManagedReference
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "countryDetails")
    private List<State> states;

    // getters / setters omitted
}
```

**State.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "state", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "id"))
public class State {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private Integer id;
    private String stateName;
    private String countryCode;
    private String stateCode;
    private String stateDetails;
    private String stateZone;

    @JsonBackReference
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "countryCode", nullable = false, insertable = false, updatable = false, foreignKey = @javax.persistence.ForeignKey(name="none",value = ConstraintMode.NO_CONSTRAINT))
    private CountryDetails countryDetails;

    // getters / setters omitted
}
```

## Now the Problem

Actually what I want the country service to return with minimal information like as shown below

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "countryName": "USA",
      "countryCode": "USA",
      "states": [
        {
          "stateCode": "WAS"
        },
        {
          "stateCode": "SOS"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "last": false,
  "totalPages": 28,
  "totalElements": 326,
  "size": 12,
  "number": 0,
  "sort": null,
  "numberOfElements": 12,
  "first": true
}
```

So for achieving that I have used Projections like as shown below

**CountryProjection .java**

```
public interface CountryProjection {
    public String getCountryName();
    public String getCountryCode();
    public List<StateProjection> getStates();
}
```

**StateProjection .java**

```
public interface StateProjection {
    public String getStateCode();
}
```

**CountryServiceImpl.java**

```
@Repository
public interface CountryRepository extends JpaRepository<CountryDetails, Integer> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT country.countryName AS countryName, country.countryCode AS countryCode FROM Country country GROUP BY country.countryId ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}", 
    countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Country country GROUP BY country.countryId ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}")
    public Page<CountryProjection> findAll(Pageable pageRequest);
}
```

But now the service is returning any of the state details like as shown below

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "countryName": "USA",
      "countryCode": "USA"
    }
  ],
  "last": false,
  "totalPages": 28,
  "totalElements": 326,
  "size": 12,
  "number": 0,
  "sort": null,
  "numberOfElements": 12,
  "first": true
}
```

How can we get the minimal state details also like as shown below

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "countryName": "USA",
      "countryCode": "USA",
      "states": [
        {
          "stateCode": "WAS"
        },
        {
          "stateCode": "SOS"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "last": false,
  "totalPages": 28,
  "totalElements": 326,
  "size": 12,
  "number": 0,
  "sort": null,
  "numberOfElements": 12,
  "first": true
}
```

Can anyone please help me on this

Comment: Why the private modifier for the getters in the Interfaces?

Comment: @Turo sorry for that...its public only

Comment: You're not using StateProjection in CountryProjection, and shouldn't these interfaces extend Serializable?

Comment: @Turo I did not get that....Can you show me an exampe

Comment: @Turo you mean I am using `State` instead of `StateProjection` with only `stateCode`. even I tried that but states details are not printing out

Comment: @Turo Is it issue with `SELECT country.countryName AS countryName, country.countryCode AS countryCode FROM Country country GROUP BY country.countryId ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}`

Comment: Forget that with the Serializable. Once I used just the stupid solution to set the unnessary fields to null and omit nulls per annotation...

Comment: @Turo Do you have any other solution for this....:(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172203/discussion-between-turo-and-alex-man).

Comment: can you try by replacing your query with - 
 `@Query(value = "SELECT country.countryName AS countryName, country.countryCode AS countryCode, country.states.stateCode AS stateCode FROM Country country GROUP BY country.countryId ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}"`

Comment: @Pradeep I have tried that also.....did'nt worked

Comment: How do you really obtain that json? Show us the VM, I don't see some properties like: `content`, `totalPages`,`numberOfElements`?

Comment: Obviously your code `public Page<CountryProjection> findAll(Pageable pageRequest);` cannot be compiled. You should provide us the code same as you currently have to exploit the bug. In my localhost, the projection work fine and output as you expected

Answer (score 1):

Try using JsonIgnore with the fields which you don't want in the return JSON

```
@JsonIgnore
private String stateDetails;
```

Comment: I can't use `@JsonIgnore` since I need those details in other service's....

Comment: In  @Query you are not querying for state code form state table, try the join to state table

Answer (score 0):

You can use `transient` keyword with the variable which you don't want within json.

ya otherwise use

```
@Expose String myString;
```

Comment: @manishsingh....Thanks for the reply....can you show me with an example

Answer (score 0):

### First idea

IMO there is something not right on the way you are doing things. I don't understand why are you defining the query directly like this:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT country.countryName AS countryName, country.countryCode AS countryCode FROM Country country GROUP BY country.countryId ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}", 
    countQuery = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Country country GROUP BY country.countryId ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}")
```

which is basically, creating a projection by *select*.

On the other hand, you are using [Interface-based Projections](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#projections.interfaces) which is yet again doing the projection, but by exposing the getters of the properties that you want to be projected. As far as I could see, you defined well the hierarchy through interfaces and it should be valid approach.

So what I am asking is, have you tried removing the `@Query` part all together?

### Second idea (in eye of the comment)

Another idea can be to use the `join fetch` [construct](https://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/from#LEFT_OUTER__INNER_JOIN_FETCH_) in `jpql` which is used tell to hibernate to load the association eagerly with the query.

```
@Query(value = "SELECT country.countryName AS countryName, country.countryCode AS countryCode, countryStates FROM Country country join fetch country.states countryStates GROUP BY country.countryId ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.... actually I cant remove @Query since I have a search query also to be searched against multiple  fields(I have not shown that in the current SO example)....

Comment: @AlexMan How do you expect a viable solution when you don't present the problem as it is?

Comment: I tried that...and got one exception ```Caused by: org.hibernate.QueryException: query specified join fetching, but the owner of the fetched association was not present in the select list```

Comment: Ok, it seems that the association is already configured as eager by something else. You can try 2 more things: 1. Remove just `fetch ` from the query or 2 : remove the join clause completely but add `country. states` to the select.

Comment: you mean like this `@Query(value = "SELECT country.countryName AS countryName, country.countryCode AS countryCode, countryStates FROM Country country  country.states countryStates GROUP BY country.countryId ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}"`

Comment: @AlexMan no. I was thinking about  `@Query(value = "SELECT country.countryName AS countryName, country.countryCode AS countryCode, countryStates as states FROM Country country join country.states countryStates GROUP BY country.countryId ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}"` or the other option like: `@Query(value = "SELECT country.countryName AS countryName, country.countryCode AS countryCode, country.countryStates as states FROM Country country GROUP BY country.countryId ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}"`

Comment: the first query worked `@Query(value = "SELECT country.countryName AS countryName, country.countryCode AS countryCode, countryStates as states FROM Country country join country.states countryStates GROUP BY country.countryId ORDER BY ?#{#pageable}"`.................but it is returning only one record for states

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173137/discussion-between-niver-and-alex-man).

Answer (score 0):

You can check the documentation of annotation :

> @JsonIgnoreProperties("fieldname")

This annotation needs to be applied on your POJO classes in your case Country*, State* mentioning the comma separated list of fields you don't need to be part of the response.

You can try this approach instead of changing to the implementation on projection style.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "id","countryDetails","countryZone"})
public class CountryDetails

@JsonIgnoreProperties({ "id","stateName","countryCode","stateDetails","stateZone"})
public class State
```

Comment: Thanks for replying... where I should apply the json ignore annotations...onto CountryDetails and State model clases....actualy If i do that then it will be always ignoring those fields....there are other services which I do require the ignored values

Comment: Yes, you are correct they would be ignored while returning the response. As in your case if you have to handle the same Object structure to behave differently in different API calls then you have to come up with the custom Mapper Utility to check the request call and derive the necessary properties to be included in the response. Look for below project with such customization.
https://github.com/monitorjbl/json-view

Answer (score 0):

You can make your `CountryService` return a DTO instead of the entity with only the fields you need.

#### Service

```java
@Service
public class CountryServiceImpl implements CountryService {

    @Autowired
    private CountryRepository countryRepository;

    @Override
    public Page<CountryDetailsDto> getAllCountryDetails(final int page, final int size) {
        return countryRepository.findAll(new PageRequest(page, size))
                .map(c -> {
                    CountryDetailsDTO dto = new CountryDetailsDTO();
                    dto.setCountryCode(c.getCountryCode());
                    dto.setCountryName(c.getCountryName());

                    dto.setStates(c.getStates().stream().map(s -> {
                        StateDto stateDto = new StateDto();
                        stateDto.setStateCode(s.getStateCode());

                        return stateDto;
                    }).collect(Collectors.toSet()));

                    return dto;
                });
    }
}
```

#### DTO

```java
public class CountryDetailsDTO {

    private String countryName;

    private String countryCode;

    private Set<StateDto> states;
}
```

```java
public class StateDto {

    private String stateCode;
}
```